# Can I turn .map array into a comma separated array with double quotes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I am tryibng to take some data from a set of twig variables and parse them into a javascript plugin. They are a set of dates listed in an array. They are first rendered onto the template like so as a string:

```
{"date":"2018-08-30, 2018-08-13, 2018-08-10, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-24, 2018-09-23, 2018-09-29, 2018-09-28"}
```

I then take this data and use it to create an array with the below function:

```
const datesNotAvailableArray = $('#datesGone').data('dates');
var arr = Object.keys(datesNotAvailableArray).map(function(k) { 
    return datesNotAvailableArray[k] 
});
```

When I `console.log(arr[0])` I get the below output:

`2018-08-30, 2018-08-13, 2018-08-10, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-24, 2018-09-23, 2018-09-29, 2018-09-28`

This is fine but what I really want to get is this sort of thing:

`["2018-08-30", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-10", etc etc]`

Can I do this within the .map function itself?

Comment: Are there other keys on the `datesNotAvailableArray` object?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `JSON.stringify(value.date.split(", "))`

Answer (score 2):

The object has just one key i.e. `date` whose value is a string containing all the dates. You need to split the string by `,` to achieve what you want and also `trim()` the strings to remove extra space left after splitting.

```js
const dateObj = {"date":"2018-08-30, 2018-08-13, 2018-08-10, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-24, 2018-09-23, 2018-09-29, 2018-09-28"}

var dates = dateObj.date.split(",").map(s => s.trim());

console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to turn the string into array, then, if you want the array-like string with double quotes, you could use .map and return `'"' + e + '"'` in each iteration, and then `join(",")` again to return the string.

```js
const obj = {"date":"2018-08-30, 2018-08-13, 2018-08-10, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-24, 2018-09-23, 2018-09-29, 2018-09-28"}

var newArr = obj.date.split(",");//<-- (", ") could remove the spaces in this case

console.log(newArr)//<-- array

newArr = newArr.map(e=>'"' + e + '"')

str = "["+newArr.join(",")+"]"

console.log(str)//<-- string with " as your example
```

Comment: `"2018-08-30", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-10", ...` vs `"2018-08-30", " 2018-08-13", " 2018-08-10", ...` - Hence you will also need a `.map()` to remove the leading space ;)

Comment: This doesn't work it puts each date into an array item like `0: "2018-08-30",1: "2018-08-30"` etc etc. I just need literally `["2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30"]`

Comment: This needs to be an array but like I have shown above. If it has to be a string then thats fine so long as the data is` ["2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30"]`

Comment: @Emeeus yes but you have it like this `['2018-08-30, 2018-08-13, 2018-08-10, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-24, 2018-09-23, 2018-09-29, 2018-09-28']` which isn't right. I need it like this `["2018-08-30", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-10", etc etc]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179119/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-emeeus).

Answer (score 0):

Simple do it with [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), It'll return an array of strings by separating the string into **substrings**,

**See the extra space after** `,` on `split()` method, it'll help you to prevent using extra methods like `map()` and `trim()` e.g `date.split(',').map(i=>i.trim())`

```js
var dates = {
  "date": "2018-08-30, 2018-08-13, 2018-08-10, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-24, 2018-09-23, 2018-09-29, 2018-09-28"
};
console.log(dates.date.split(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const datesNotAvailableArray = $('#datesGone').data('dates');
datesNotAvailableArray['date'].split(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {"date":"2018-08-30, 2018-08-13, 2018-08-10, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-24, 2018-09-23, 2018-09-29, 2018-09-28"}
const result = obj .date.split(',').map(s => s.trim());


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking more for something like this:

```
var arr = Object.keys(datesNotAvailableArray).map(k => obj[k].split(','))[0]
console.log(arr[0); // ["2018-08-30", " 2018-08-13", " 2018-08-10", " 2018-08-01", " 2018-08-26", " 2018-09-27", " 2018-09-26", " 2018-09-25", " 2018-09-24", " 2018-09-23", " 2018-09-29", " 2018-09-28"]
```

It would get the result you want but it's really only useful if you have other keys from your source object. However, I would advice against it as doing so would lose information as to which output array index was mapped from which key of the source object.

Any of the previous answers would be a better approach than what you were trying to do with `.map`